# Django Modelform Redirect to form-submitted content

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect

Disclaimer: Still very new at this.

I've managed to get a site up and running that catalogs rock climbs. I've got a functioning form that allows users to submit a new item to the catalog, but have been unable to figure out how to redirect them to the newly created page. Here's my code:

("..." in place of what I think is irrelevant and bulky code. Let me know if you need it in!)

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyDB
        fields = (...)
    def save(self):
        instance = super(PostForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.slug = slugify (instance.name)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

views.py:

```
def post_new(request):
    things = MyDB.objects.order_by('name')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            created_at = timezone.now()
            updated_at = timezone.now()
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'DB.html', {
                'things': things,
            })
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'things/submit_thing.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class MyDB(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

and urls.py:

```
url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.thing_detail, name='thing_detail'),
url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
```

Right now i Just have it redirecting to a static html page because I can't figure out how to get it to load the newly created page. I've tried using the redirect function, but am unsure how to designate the newly created page as the destination.

Thank you!

Edit: Here is the working code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse

def post_new(request):
    things = MyDB.objects.order_by('name')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            created_at = timezone.now()
            updated_at = timezone.now()
            thing = form.save()    
            return redirect(reverse('thing_detail', kwargs={'slug': thing.slug})
            )
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'things/submit_thing.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Where do you want to redirect the user?

Comment: To the slugified version of the "name" field. For instance, if they submitted the form with the name "Bob is great," it would redirect to /things/bob-is-great/, which is the generated view of the data they just submitted

Comment: Assign the result of `form.save()` to a variable, e.g. `instance = form.save()`. Then you can use `instance.slug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

You can use the `redirect` shortcut and `reverse` function to reverse-resolve the name, in your case:

```
thing = form.save()    
redirect(reverse('thing_detail', kwargs={'slug': thing.slug))
```

Comment: Tried plugging that into my code, as well as adding it to the import in the header, but am not having much luck. Getting a "QuerySet' object has no attribute 'slug' error. I updated the original post with my updated code.

Comment: @Josh With `thing` I meant a `MyDB` instance, see the edit

Comment: Note you don't need `reverse` with `redirect` — `redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)` does the same as `redirect(reverse('thing_detail', kwargs={'slug': thing.slug))`.

Comment: Works! Had to add "return" to the start, and change some syntax with the )'s and }'s, but it's now working. Thanks! I added the working code to my original post.